# How to set help information for pscmdlet class

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet, remarks

I'm writing a powershell module in c# that's comprised of a bunch of powershell cmdlets.

for example:

> get-application

When I declare the class

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Application")]
    public class GetApplication : PSCmdlet
```

I can do things like provide parameters for this cmdlet and helpful messages about the parameter itself.

I'm trying to provide more documentation in my classes so that a command like

> get-help get-application

will provide a description about the cmdlet itself in the REMARKS section.

Any idea how i can add that in visual studio 2013?

Comment: This has been answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46752476/6326441.