# Implement Get-Help PSCmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, remarks

I am writing PowerShell Cmdlets using the PSCmdlet class in C#.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Employee")]
public class GetEmployee : PSCmdlet
```

I want to provide more information in Remarks, Description, Synopsis section of Get-Help Get-Employee

Anyone knows how to add/fill these sections?

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// <para type="synopsis">This is the cmdlet synopsis.</para>
/// <para type="description">This is part of the longer cmdlet description.</para>
/// <para type="description">Also part of the longer cmdlet description.</para>
/// </summary>
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Employee")]
public class GetEmployee : PSCmdlet
```

See this blog post [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/software-tools/documenting-your-powershell-binary-cmdlets/) for more detailed examples.